# How to get ESLint --fix to also run prettier --write

Tags: javascript, eslint, prettier

It is possible to configure your `.eslintrc` so that running `eslint --fix` would run also run `prettier --write` as well?

Right now I need to do `prettier --write && eslint --fix` and I was hoping I could just run the one command.

**Update**

Using `prettier-eslint` "works" except it does not apply my custom overrides:

My `.eslintrc.js` looks like

```
module.exports = { 
  extends: [
    'prettier',
  ],
  plugins: [
    'prettier',
  ],
  rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': [
      'error',
      {
        'singleQuote': true,
      },
    ],
  }
};
```

Then I have a dummy file.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const foo = () => {
    return path;
}
```

If I run `eslint ./file.js` I get expected output:

> error  Replace `"path"` with `'path'`   prettier/prettier

But when I run `prettier-eslint --eslint-config-path .eslintrc.js --write ./file.js` it keeps the `"` and does not replace it with `'`

I do not want to have a separate file for prettierrc and want to keep both in one file.

Comment: If you're doing this on git hooks. you can simply use husky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a great package called [prettier-eslint](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-eslint) that we've used at work before. It will format using prettier and then run `eslint --fix` on your code. We liked it, give it a try!

Comment: This is ignoring my eslint rules though; I'll update my question